# Unit Test: @Inject not injecting service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit

here is my entity

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String externalUserId;
    private String email;
    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private boolean active;

    public User(@Nonnull final String externalUserId, @Nonnull final String email,
                @Nonnull final String clientId, @Nonnull final String clientSecret, final boolean active) {
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.externalUserId = externalUserId;
        this.email = email;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

and a `UserService`

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

@Stateless
public class UserService {
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @Nonnull
    public User createUser(@Nonnull final User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

I also have `DBConfig` as

```
import javax.annotation.sql.DataSourceDefinition;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@DataSourceDefinition(
        name = "java:app/oauth/testDB",
        className = "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource",
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test"
)
@Stateless
public class DBConfig {
}
```

`test/src/main/resources/persistence.xml` as

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="testDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.self.oauth.persistence.entities.User</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My test looks like

```
public class UserTest {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testUser() {
        final User user = new User(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "test@test.com", "clientId", "clientSecret", true);
        userService.createUser(user);
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

and I get `NullPointeException` on `userService`

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you expect to perform the injection in your unit test?

Comment: Why do you assume/expect that `userService` should be anything other than `null`?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not assume anything, I am trying to learn to persist object in database using JPA and facing this issue

Comment: Right. So why did you write it like this? Why should `userService` be non-null? What is going to process the `@Inject` annotation in your test as it stands?

Comment: Maybe you need to look at http://arquillian.org/. The JUnit test framework don't undestant `java-ee` annotations.

Comment: Injection gets handled by a DI capable container (Inversion of control). A simple unit test does not involve such stuff. To enable injection you can use an embedded ejb container or Arquillian. This kind of test then wouldn't be called unit test. It's integration testing.

Comment: That's rather off topic, but that is one reason why I prefer using an external container like Spring than all integrated JEE DI : same context and same dependency injection in test and deployed versions.

Answer (score 2):

Injection is handled by a Java EE Container in execution time. In particular and checking your piece of code, an EJB container would handle the injection of UserService since it is declared to be a Stateless bean. When you deploy your entire application a container is set and injection works fine. When executing unit tests (I guess using junit) none of the services are launched, and any @Injection will end up with the variable set to null, because no container will be launched either.

The idea is that unit tests should be only used for testing pieces of code independently of external ones like the one contained in other classes. However, in your case it looks like you want an integration test, so, you really need all services to be up since you want to check that an object is persisted in the database. For that, you need you need to launch also a container. A good way of doing that, is using [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/).

For instance, in your case, the test should be something like this:

```
package org.arquillian.example;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class  UserTest{

  @Deployment
  public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
      .addClass(UserService.class)
      .addClass(User.class)
      .addClass(DBConfig.class)
      .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
  }

  @Inject
  private UserService userService;

  @Test
  public void testUser() {
    final User user = new User(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "test@test.com", "clientId", "clientSecret", true);
    userService.createUser(user);
    assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```